# Converting between a vim replace and a perl pie replace

Tags: vim, regex, perl

So I have a file test.txt, that contains,

```
home -> range
```

If I edit the file in vim and run the command `%s/^\(.*\)->\(.*\)$/\2 ::= \1 ;/g` it converts the file to

```
range ::= home  ;
```

which is what I want. However if I run

```
 perl -pi -e 's/^\(.*\)->\(.*\)$/\2 ::= \1 ;/g' test.txt
```

which I think should do the same, I get no change - can someone tell me what's gone wrong? I suspect that something needs escaping but I've thrown all manner of combinations of escape at it... plus I'd like some general rules about the conversion between the two formats...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl you dont escape the capturing brackets, also it is conventional to use $1,$2 instead of \1,\2 for the capturing variables.

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(.*)->(.*)$/$2 ::= $1 ;/g' test.txt
```

It is an unfortunate fact of life that the [regexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax) (RE) used in many common tools (vim, sed, awk, perl) are all subtly different. Some tools have an option to use Perl REs, POSIX Basic REs (BRE) or POSIX Extended REs (ERE).

---

`perldoc perlre` has this to say on `$1` vs `\1` in the replacement part of a substitution expression

> Some people get too used to writing things like:
>
> ```
> $pattern =~ s/(\W)/\\\1/g;
> ```
>
> This is grandfathered for the RHS of a substitute to avoid shocking the
>   sed addicts, but it's a dirty habit to get into.  That's because in
>   PerlThink, the righthand side of an "s///" is a double-quoted string.
>   "\1" in the usual double-quoted string means a control-A.  The custom-
>   ary Unix meaning of "\1" is kludged in for "s///".  However, if you get
>   into the habit of doing that, you get yourself into trouble if you then
>   add an "/e" modifier.